# "Why wasn't ya"

Tags: dialects, cinema

In "Wrath of Man", a 2021 movie with Jason Statham as "H", he's being told "what you didn't hear, is that I was meant to be drivin' the truck that day" to which he responds: "*why wasn't yaʰ*" (note the aspiration at the end).

What dialect of English would be spoken like that?

Comment: Many "non-standard" English dialects would use that. Using **was** instead of **were** and ya instead of you. The so-called standard form would be: Why weren't you?

Comment: The combination of "wasn't" and "ya" is not that common, and the addition of an aspiration at the end of the "ya" makes it quite interesting and noteworthy enough to come here (as opposed to `ell.`) and ask the question. It's made more interesting by the facts that the movie is set in the US, the actor is English, as is the character, and the character's cover is Irish. One could guess that it's just the actor's native dialect, but while Statham grew up in Derbyshire, he also lived in Norfolk from possibly a young age (his Wikipedia page is unclear on that). And then he is, you know, an actor.

Comment: Not a huge fan of JS movies but from what I have seen he has a London accent. In this case it sounds like he's trying to do an Irish accent to fit his cover, but how successful it is I don't know. Maybe have a listen to some Irish English on YT and see if it sounds like that is what he was going for.

Comment: Indeed I was a huge fan of the original Transporter movie and have since given up on watching movies with him in it. This one I enjoyed, again, though! And from a guy who started out as a street vendor, you can't complain about his acting, either (saying that as a former amateur stage actor). London Soho base layer plus Irish imitation on top of it might fit the bill...